# MongoDb says duplicate error even it does not exist in the collection using Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

This is my `customer` schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { isEmail } = require('validator');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const requiredString = {
    type: String,
    required: true
}

const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your first name'],
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required:[true, 'Please enter your last name']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase:true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        validate: [isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email'],
        lowercase: true
    },
    address: requiredString,
    mobile: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        maxlength: [11, 'Minimum length is 11 number']
    },
    barangay: requiredString,
    city: requiredString,
    province: requiredString,
    postalCode:requiredString,
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter a password'],
        minlength: [8, 'Minimum password length is 8 characters']
    },
    verified: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    status: requiredString,
    code: requiredString,
    profilePicture: {
        type: String
    }
}); 

// validate for uniqueness
customerSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

// fire a function before saving to database
customerSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password,salt);
    next();
})

// create static login method for user
customerSchema.statics.login = async function(username,password) {
    const customer = await this.findOne({ username });
    if(customer) {
        const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password,customer.password);
        if(auth) {
            return customer;
        }
        throw Error('Incorrect password');
    }
    throw Error('This username doesn\'t exist');
}

customerSchema.statics.resetPassword = async function(id,password) {
    const customer = await this.findById(id);
    if(customer) {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        const newPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,salt);
        return newPassword;
    }
}

const CustomerModel = mongoose.model('customer', customerSchema);
module.exports = CustomerModel;
```

This is my code in signing up in my `controller.js`

```
module.exports.customer_signup_post = async (req, res) => {
    const { firstname,lastname,username,email,mobile,address,barangay,city,province,postalCode,password } = req.body;
    const verified = false;
    const code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    const status = 'active';

    const htmlContent = `
    <h1>Hi ${firstname}!</h1>
    
    <h2>${code}</h2>
    <p>It seems like you registered with this account. Please use this code to verify your account</p>

    <p>Thank you for using Tulin Bicycle Shop! Enjoy Shopping!</p>
    `
    try {

        const newCustomer = await Customer.create({ firstname,lastname,username,email,mobile,address,barangay,city,province,postalCode,password,verified,status,code });
        const info = await transporter.sendMail({
            from: `'Tulin Bicycle Shop' <${process.env.MAIL_ACCOUNT}>`,
            to: `${newCustomer.email}`,
            subject: 'Account verification',
            html: htmlContent
        });
        
        console.log("Message was sent: " + info.response);
        res.status(201).json({ mssg: `${newCustomer.firstname} has been created, please check your email for verification`, customerId: newCustomer._id,redirect:`/verify/${newCustomer._id}` });
    } 
    catch(err) {
        const errors = handleErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }
}
```

**This is the error being shown when I try to signup new user**

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: capstone.customers index: username_1 dup key: { username: "neknek" }
```

This is my code in React.js

```
import { AiOutlineLoading3Quarters } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate,Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import StepOne from '../../../components/shop/signup.jsx/StepOne';
import StepTwo from '../../../components/shop/signup.jsx/StepTwo';
import StepThree from '../../../components/shop/signup.jsx/StepThree';

const Signup = () => {
   
    const [firstname,setFirstname] = useState('');
    const [lastname,setLastname] = useState('')
    const [username,setUsername] = useState('');
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [mobile,setMobile] = useState('');
    const [address,setAddress] = useState('');
    const [barangay,setBarangay] = useState('');
    const [city,setCity] = useState('');
    const [province,setProvince] = useState('');
    const [postalCode,setPostalCode] = useState('');
    const [password,setPassword] = useState('');
    const [confirmPassword,setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

    const [success,setSuccess] = useState('');
    const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const [passErr,setPassErr] = useState('');
    const [usernameErr,setUsernameErr] = useState('');
    const [emailErr,setEmailErr] = useState('');
    const [mobileErr,setMobileErr] = useState('');
    const [passLimitErr,setPassLimitErr] = useState('');

    const [activeStep,setActiveStep] = useState('step one'); 

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const onSignup = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsLoading(true);
       
        if(password !== confirmPassword) {
            setPassErr('Password doesn\'t match, please check your password');
            setTimeout(() => {
                setPassErr('');
            },2000);
        } else {
            axios.post('/customer',{ firstname,lastname,username,email,mobile,address,barangay,city,province,postalCode,password })
            .then((data) => {
                setSuccess(data.data.mssg);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    navigate(data.data.redirect);
                },2000)
                setIsLoading(false);
            }).catch((err) => {
                
                setEmailErr(err.response.data.errors.email);
                setPassLimitErr(err.response.data.errors.password);
                setUsernameErr(err.response.data.errors.username);
                setMobileErr(err.response.data.errors.mobile);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setEmailErr('');
                    setUsernameErr('');
                    setPassLimitErr('');
                    setMobileErr('');
                },2000)
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
        }
    }

  return (
    <>
        <Helmet><title>Tulin Bicycle Shop | Signup</title></Helmet>
        <div className="content signup-bg h-full overflow-hidden">
            <div className="max-content flex items-center justify-center w-1/2">
                <img className="object-cover h-4/5" src="/image/bike-bg.png" alt="Bike background" />
                <div className="bg-white h-4/5 w-2/5 relative" onSubmit={onSignup}>
                    <div className="absolute flex items-center gap-2 top-0 right-0 p-4">
                        <h2>Already have an account?</h2>
                        <Link to='/login' className="rounded-full border border-gray-700 p-2 shadow-xl">Sign in</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="px-8 py-24">
                        <h1 className="text-gray-800 text-5xl">Sign up</h1>
                        <span>Create your account</span>
                        { isLoading && <h2 className="text-sm text-green-500 flex items-center gap-2"><AiOutlineLoading3Quarters className="animate-spin" />Please wait...</h2> }
                        { emailErr && <h2 className="text-sm text-red-500">{ emailErr }</h2> } 
                        { usernameErr && <h2 className="text-sm text-red-500">{ usernameErr }</h2> }
                        { mobileErr && <h2 className="text-sm text-red-500">{ mobileErr }</h2> }
                        <p className="text-sm text-green-500">{ success }</p>
                        <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2">
                        {/* Pages button */}
                            <button onClick={() => setActiveStep('step one')} className={`rounded-full w-5 h-5 border border-gray-700 flex justify-center items-center p-1 text-xs ${activeStep === 'step one' && 'bg-gray-300'}`}>1</button>
                            <button onClick={() => setActiveStep('step two')} className={`rounded-full w-5 h-5 border border-gray-700 flex justify-center items-center p-1 text-xs ${activeStep === 'step two' && 'bg-gray-300'}`}>2</button>
                            <button onClick={() => setActiveStep('step three')} className={`rounded-full w-5 h-5 border border-gray-700 flex justify-center items-center p-1 text-xs ${activeStep === 'step three' && 'bg-gray-300'}`}>3</button>

                        </div>
                        <form className="flex flex-col gap-2 mt-1" onSubmit={onSignup}>
                            {/* First Step */}
                            { activeStep === 'step one' && 
                            <StepOne 
                                firstname={firstname}
                                setFirstname={setFirstname}
                                lastname={lastname}
                                setLastname={setLastname}
                                username={username}
                                setUsername={setUsername}
                                email={email}
                                setEmail={setEmail}
                                usernameErr={usernameErr}
                                emailErr={emailErr}
                                setActiveStep={setActiveStep}
                            /> }
                            {/* Second Step */}
                            { activeStep === 'step two' && 
                            <StepTwo 
                                mobile={mobile}
                                address={address}
                                barangay={barangay}
                                city={city}
                                province={province}
                                postalCode={postalCode}
                                setMobile={setMobile}
                                setAddress={setAddress}
                                setBarangay={setBarangay}
                                setCity={setCity}
                                setProvince={setProvince}
                                setPostalCode={setPostalCode}
                                setActiveStep={setActiveStep}
                            /> }
                            {/* Step Three */}
                            { activeStep === 'step three' && 
                            <StepThree 
                                password={password}
                                setPassword={setPassword}
                                confirmPassword={confirmPassword}
                                setConfirmPassword={setConfirmPassword}
                                passLimitErr={passLimitErr}
                                passErr={passErr}
                                setActiveStep={setActiveStep}
                            /> }
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

The main problem is it always shows that error when I try to signup new users, it will display that error but will be inserted the data anyway. I want to fix this problem and I tried to drop indexes but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, the problem is in the frontend part. The form tag sends a data when you're using a button inside it, what I did was created an onClick event in the signup button then call the function `onSignup` in my `StepThree` component.

```
const StepThree = ({ password,setPassword,confirmPassword,setConfirmPassword,passLimitErr,passErr,setActiveStep,onSignup }) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full">
         <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input className="user-auth" type="password" placeholder="Password" 
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                value={password}
                required
            />
            <span className="pass-error">{ passLimitErr }</span>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
            <label htmlFor="confirm password">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input className="user-auth" type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" 
                onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                value={confirmPassword}
                required
            />
            <span className="pass-error">{ passErr }</span>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
            <div onClick={() => setActiveStep('step two')} className="flex-col flex gap-2 text-center cursor-pointer">
                <span className="bg-gray-900 text-gray-100 p-2 rounded">Previous</span>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-col flex gap-2">
                <button onClick={onSignup} className="signup-btn-user">Signup</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default StepThree
```